# ggplot2, fitting data with log2 or log10 doesn't affect the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted a display a geom_smooth with a natural log   and this code works fine:

```
    df <- iris
iris_logplot <- ggplot(df, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, colour = Species))

iris_logplot + stat_summary(fun.y =median, geom = "point") + stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, aes(group = Species), geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~log(x))
```

now I want to display a geom_smooth with a log whose base is 2 and I apply this code:

```
df <- iris
iris_logplot <- ggplot(df, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, colour = Species))

iris_logplot + stat_summary(fun.y =median, geom = "point") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, aes(group = Species), geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2) + geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~log2(x))
```

Why the  plots are the same?

Thanks

Comment: What does this copy of `iris` look like? It seems like you've changed the column names to lowercase and replaced the periods with underscores—this is fine, but let us know—but you've got color assigned to iris in your `aes`. Should this actually be species? Similarly, you later refer to a column `Type`. Please post the data you're working with

Comment: I just tried to make a reproducible example. The real database I'm working with, contains other variables. The focus here is why when typing log2 or log there is no difference?

Comment: So now I've posted exactly the code i'm using. Thanks for the suggestion (I'm sure there will be some other guy that would complain about this)

Comment: Wait, but now there's no data for us to work with! Using a modified version of the iris dataset was fine, you just need to be clear about what's changed in it from the standard version, e.g. what the `iris` and `Type` columns are. Or you can post a sample of your real data

Comment: Gianluca, if you pass along a reproductible example it would help us help you. Look here for guides on how to provide it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've tried to improve the question now and i've modified the code accordingly. It should now look like a reproducible example. For istance you can run the same codes in R and it doesn't display any error but the plots (which are the same).   Thanks a lot!

Comment: From a model-fit perspective, the base of the logarithm doesn't matter. When you change from log_e to log_2, the resulting fit should be the same. since `log_2(x) = log_e(x) / log_e(2)` it is just multiplying by a constant.

Comment: ok, so what I want to do is to see whether my data fits with the so called Fitt's Law:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law and the formula of this Law is ID = log2(2D/W).  where D is constant, ID "in iris terms" would be Sepal.Width, and W would be Sepal.Lenght. How can I have a curve which displays whether my data adhere to a fitt's law? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines are the same because multiplying a feature in a linear model by a constant does not change the fit, the coefficients are just divided by the same constant. The "change of base" formula tells us that `log_b(x) = log_a(x) / log_a(b)`.

We can verify this by examining the models:

```
m_log_e = lm(Sepal.Width ~ log(Sepal.Length) * Species, data = iris)
m_log_2 = lm(Sepal.Width ~ log2(Sepal.Length) * Species, data = iris)

summary(m_log_e)
# Call:
# lm(formula = Sepal.Width ~ log(Sepal.Length) * Species, data = iris)
# 
# Residuals:
#      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -0.71398 -0.15310 -0.00419  0.16595  0.60237 
# 
# Coefficients:
#                                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)                          -2.9663     0.8872  -3.343 0.001055 ** 
# log(Sepal.Length)                     3.9760     0.5512   7.214 2.86e-11 ***
# Speciesversicolor                     2.3355     1.1899   1.963 0.051595 .  
# Speciesvirginica                      3.0464     1.1639   2.617 0.009807 ** 
# log(Sepal.Length):Speciesversicolor  -2.0626     0.7087  -2.910 0.004186 ** 
# log(Sepal.Length):Speciesvirginica   -2.4373     0.6811  -3.579 0.000471 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.272 on 144 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.6237,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.6106 
# F-statistic: 47.73 on 5 and 144 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

summary(m_log_2)
# Call:
# lm(formula = Sepal.Width ~ log2(Sepal.Length) * Species, data = iris)
# 
# Residuals:
#      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -0.71398 -0.15310 -0.00419  0.16595  0.60237 
# 
# Coefficients:
#                                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)                           -2.9663     0.8872  -3.343 0.001055 ** 
# log2(Sepal.Length)                     2.7560     0.3820   7.214 2.86e-11 ***
# Speciesversicolor                      2.3355     1.1899   1.963 0.051595 .  
# Speciesvirginica                       3.0464     1.1639   2.617 0.009807 ** 
# log2(Sepal.Length):Speciesversicolor  -1.4297     0.4913  -2.910 0.004186 ** 
# log2(Sepal.Length):Speciesvirginica   -1.6894     0.4721  -3.579 0.000471 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.272 on 144 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.6237,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.6106 
# F-statistic: 47.73 on 5 and 144 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comparing the summaries, you can convince yourself that the fits are the same - the residuals are the same, the statistics are the same, the intercepts are the same, the only difference are the coefficients for terms including `Sepal.Length`. We can divide the coefficients:

```
coef(m_log_e) / coef(m_log_2)
#                         (Intercept)                   log(Sepal.Length)                   Speciesversicolor                    Speciesvirginica 
#                            1.000000                            1.442695                            1.000000                            1.000000 
# log(Sepal.Length):Speciesversicolor  log(Sepal.Length):Speciesvirginica 
#                            1.442695                            1.442695
```

And see that the terms involving `Sepal.Length` are off by a fixed ratio. And what is that ratio?

```
1 / log(2)
# [1] 1.442695
```

It is `1 /log(2)`, because of the change of base formula referenced at the start of this answer.